# Retrieve list of repositories and their tag versions in one call

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, sh

I have two azure CLI queries.

```
az acr repository list
```

to retrieve a list of repositories in my container registry

```
az acr repository show-tags
```

to retrieve version tag for each of the repositories returned by the first query

This results in an initial call to retrieve a list and then 1 call for each repository returned. Is there an alternative that would reduce the number of calls required to one? Retrieval of a list of repositories and their version in 1 go.

show-tags command needs a repository parameter that is mandatory and I am unaware of any other commands that would return the information I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK currently there is no alternative that would retrieve list of repositories and their versions in one go. I recommend sharing this feedback by posting it here -> https://feedback.azure.com/forums/903958-azure-container-registry

Just a suggestion which you might already be aware of is, for now as a workaround you may develop a small script to fetch all the repositories using the list command and feed each repository name in sequence one after the other as input to the show tags command and concatenate the outputs of all repositories.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 4):

As of now, it's impossible to complete it in one call.

As someone already mentioned, the least call step is to create a script to get all the repositories(store the repositories in a variable), then in a loop, use `az acr repository show-tags` to get their tags.

The sameple scripts as blow:

```
result="$(az acr repository list -n ACR_name --output tsv)"

for i in $result; do az acr repository show-tags -n ACR_name --repository $i; done
```

Test result as below:

[image]

Comment: That is what I am doing currently, thanks for the confirmation :)

Answer (score 3):

To get a list of full images names that you can use with `docker pull`, do this:

```sh
export REGISTRY=mycontainerregistry
```

```sh
#!/bin/bash
mycontainers=$(az acr repository list --name $REGISTRY --output tsv)
for i in $mycontainers
do
    echo -n "$REGISTRY.azurecr.io/$i:"
    az acr repository show-tags -n $REGISTRY --repository $i --output tsv|tail -1
done
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried the above script posted by `bbaassssiiee`, and it appears to work to retrieve just the latest images. If you'd like to generate a list of ALL images in a repository using a `IMAGE_REPO:TAG` format, I created the following bash script similar to the one above to do exactly that:

```
#!/bin/bash
    
registry_name='REGISTRY_NAME'
destination='LOCATION_TO_STORE_LIST'
az acr login --name $registry_name
touch $destination

repos="$(az acr repository list -n $registry_name --output tsv)"

for i in $repos; do
    images="$(az acr repository show-tags -n $registry_name --repository $i --output tsv --orderby time_desc)"
    for j in $images; do
        echo $i":"$j >> $destination;
    done;
done;
```

The only variables you need to set are `registry_name` and `destination` to store the list. I wanted to do a little cleanup of our container registry because there are a lot of unused images so the idea was to identify which images we need to keep from the list, remove them, and then create a script to run `az acr repository delete` against the remaining images to clean up the registry and decrease the amount of storage we're using for the container registry to avoid unnecessary costs.