# Microsoft Azure CLI Command to query 2 Different Build versions from ACR

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-container-registry

'''On ACR we have 1 repository with 2 different application versions—one is 2020.1.1 and the other one is 2021.1.1

An example is given below:

```
   acr.azure.io/app1:2021.1.2
   acr.azure.io/app1:2021.1.1
   acr.azure.io/app1:2020.1.2
   acr.azure.io/app1:2020.1.1
```

Is there any way I can query the build version using azure CLI

```
az acr repository show-tags -n acr.qzure.io --repository app1 --orderby time_desc --query "[0]"
```

The above command always gives acr.azure.io/app1:2021.1.2 as an output

Is there any other way? Does it always query the highest version of 2020 or 2021?
'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the below command very useful to query the specific version.

```
az acr repository show-tags -n acr.qzure.io --repository app1 --orderby time_desc --output tsv | grep -e "2020.1.1.*" | head -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `--orderby` parameter to order items by time ascending or descending order. Then you can query each item by the index of an array. You can check the time with `--detail` parameter. See [az acr repository show-tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr/repository?view=azure-cli-latest#az_acr_repository_show_tags)

For example,

```
az acr repository show-tags -n acr.qzure.io --repository app1 --orderby time_desc --detail
```

with query like this

```
 --orderby time_desc --query "[0]" 

 --orderby time_desc --query "[1]" 

 --orderby time_desc --query "[2]" 

 --orderby time_desc --query "[3]"
```

For more reference, you could see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55223531/retrieve-list-of-repositories-and-their-tag-versions-in-one-call).

Comment: Thank you, Nancy, Is there any other way we can query the 2020 application version?

Every day we are getting 2020 and 2021 application build versions, with the above-mentioned technique It will be very difficult to get the 2020 latest version.